# Booting KNOPPIX DVD to ram from grub prompt

Tags: boot, grub, knoppix

I'm trying to boot KNOPPIX to RAM from the grub prompt.

Booting using

```
grub> set root=(cd1)
grub> linux /boot/isolinux/linux lang=en
grub> initrd /boot/isolinux/minirt.gz
grub> boot
```

works just fine, but adding the `toram` parameter causes it to get stuck after pressing Enter on `boot`.

I've seen [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102529/booting-a-knoppix-iso-from-grub-device-uri-madness) where the poster uses `loopback loop /boot/iso/knoppix.iso` and `bootfrom=.../boot/iso/knoppix.iso`. I've tried adding both using `/KNOPPIX/bootonly.iso`, which is the only .iso file I was able to find on the CD, neither of which helped.

I know I should be able to boot the OS to ram from grub as I've done this with other distros. Is there something I'm missing?